# How to retrieve highlighted text and display in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to insert the highlighted text in database. But I don't know how to display the highlighted text in html.

Below is my HTML code

```
<div onmouseup="highlightSelection('yellow')">
 Please select to highlight text with yellow color <div>
```

Below is my Javascript code

```
<script>  function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
var range, sel = window.getSelection();

if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
}
console.log(range);
document.designMode = "on";
if (range) {
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
// Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
    document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
}
document.designMode = "off";}

function highlightSelection(colour) {

var range, sel;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    try {
        if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8 case
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
}}
```

below is my Script link

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/9ookrny3/embed/"></script>
```

below is my CSS

```
<style>::selection {
background: yellow;}::-moz-selection { background: yellow;}</style>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: need to display highlighted text after reloading the page. for that i m storing the text in DB.. but the text which i have highlighted that is static html.

Comment: That's still not a question, how do you get the text out of the DB? Can you use something like mark.js?

Comment: Thanks for reply. This text is static html file(hard code) . its not from DB.

Comment: So what are you using your database for then? It's not like the text is magically going to change to whatever you store somewhere

Comment: I have one html file with few content(static). I want to hightlight(marked) few words and once highlight, It should be appear after page reload.Database i m using to store the highlighted word. here i have not mention the code for DB.